# Is there a way of determining if two matrices have any relations?

Tags: matrices, relations

If I have two matrices A and B, is there a way to determine if ANY relations exist?

e.g. $AAB^{-1}=B^{-1}ABBA^{-1}, BABAB^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}=ABAAB$, etc

Basically that every permutation of A, B and their inverses yields a unique matrix (apart from cases where a matrix is adjacent to it's inverse, which of course simplify)

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Jesse! Welcome to MSE. In the future, it would be very helpful if you would format your questions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference): it makes them much easier to read. Great question though. Happy mathing!

Comment: Endow the square of the space of matrices with the product measure of Lebesgue measures on each entry. Then each given relation you have in mind holds on a subset of measure zero and there are countably many such relations hence they all simultaneously fail on a subset of the set of matrices of full measure.

Answer (score 3):

For general matrices $A$ and $B$? No chance whatsoever.

Even the case $A,B\in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is nontrivial; see for instance [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.mmj/1028999969) for a few examples of sufficient conditions.

Comment: Wait, so you can't tell in general if given the matrices, but the paper shows how to construct some (in the 2x2 case)?

Comment: @JesseNicholas right.

Answer (score 3):

When the matrices are invertible you may narrow down the search if they have different values of their determinant since $\det(A)^{n_A} \det(B)^{n_B}=1$, with $n_A$ and $n_B$ denoting the total number of appearances of $A$ and $B$, respectively, and with sign.